# Plugin integrate in forum to show user profiles

Tags: plugins

What would I need to use for the user profiles to allow them to list their skills and experiences, and to allow other users to search in Forum?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few plugins able to handle your request:

1. [Ultimate Member](https://ultimatemember.com/) : Used this to build a community site with experts in different specialties.
2. [Peepso](https://www.peepso.com/) : A full featured community building plugin

Both can be customized if needed.